# How to do multiple group functions at a time in my sql if the value is dynamic?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, stored-procedures

I wanted to print sum value here, but I am not able to refer v.id inside from clause derived query.

In the below query I am getting start and end time grouped by date by vehicle
So here I want to take difference between min start time and max end time FOR each day of a vehicle and want to sum all the differences

```
'Select 
(select sum(a)
from (
      SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(t1.start_time),max(t1.end_time)) a 
      from trip t1  where t1.vehicle_id =v.id 
       group by CAST(t1.start_time AS DATE)) a) as totalHours 
from vehicle v where v.id IN (?);  '
```

I also tried in this way , Here I am not able to do multiple group functions
Error: Invalid use of group function

```
'SELECT  
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(vt.start_time),Max(vt.end_time))) totalHours 

LEFT JOIN trip vt 
ON vt.id = (
            select t1.id 
            from trip t1 
            where t1.vehicle_id =v.id  
            group by CAST(t1.start_time AS DATE)
           )
from vehicle v where v.id IN (?)'
```

Please help me with any other available ways to calculate the sum.

Comment: "Please help me with any other available ways to calculate the sum." Provide example data on sqlfiddle.com and provide expected results based on the example data

Comment: Where does dynamic come into it?

Comment: In regard to the first of your two queries posted: You want to use `v.id` in the `GROUP BY` in the inner query? That won't work as `v.id` is not in `trip`. But you can use `t1.vehicle_id`, it's identical to `v.id` because of the `where t1.vehicle_id =v.id`.

Comment: Here vehicle id's will be dynamic, application will hit this query with multiple vehicle id's @P.Salmon

Comment: @stickybit 
in the first query I cannot be able to refer v.id in from clause derived table.
"from trip t1  where t1.vehicle_id =v.id "
here v is not identifying

Comment: @vinod j: Of course you cannot use `v.id` in a `FROM`, it's a column, not a table. I'm afraid, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I got the result

  '  SELECT id,sum(timesec)

    FROM (

    SELECT v.id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(start_time),max(end_time)) timesec
      FROM vehicle v 
     JOIN (SELECT vehicle_id,t1.start_time,end_time
                   from trip t1 
           ) vt ON v.id = vt.vehicle_id
             group by id,CAST(start_time AS DATE)      
                 ) a
 group by id'